# Documents/Inbox folder for opening file from another App

Tags: iphone, inbox, uti

I registered my app to associate some filetypes. so when the file comes in the mail attachment, I use my app to open the file. My app will automatically create a "Inbox" folder inside my Documents folder, and save the file in "Inbox". This Inbox is special, because it prevents me to create a folder or move a file into it by program.

Question comes to me is:

1. What is the special for the "Inbox"? Can I change some setting, and
   it will allow me to create a subfolder inside?
2. What is normal solution for this?

Thanks

Cullen

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Inbox is just a link to your email stuff. You should copy the files from there to your documents directory with`NSFileManager`.

Comment: Inbox is incoming files sent via URL schemes and UIDocumentInteractionController file open calls.